# Cloud/RESTful interface for Image/GraphicsMagick

Tags: imagemagick, cloud, graphicsmagick

I'm looking for a cloud service to where I can upload images and get them cropped / resized.

Basically I'm looking for zencoder, but for images instead of video.

I know about cloudinary but it forces you to store the images on their system so that they can jack up the fees. Is there any good alternative to it that's reputable?

Comment: For anyone interested in rolling their own, [Photon](https://github.com/1000Memories/photon-core) provides an excellent base.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blitline can do that for you.

[http://www.blitline.com/docs/quickstart](https://www.blitline.com/v3/home/features)

Here is an example on how to do this through curl:

```
curl "http://api.blitline.com/job" \
  -d json='{ "application_id": "sgOob0A3b3RdYaqwTEJCpA", 
             "src" : "http://www.google.com/logos/2011/yokoyama11-hp.jpg", 
             "functions" : [ {"name": "blur", 
                              "params" : {"radius" : 0.0, "sigma" : 2.0}, 
                              "save" : { "image_identifier" : "some_id" }} ]}'
```

Here is the list of image [functions](https://helpdocs.blitline.com/article/MraLE6tVOY-functions) that can be used.

Note:

- The source image should be public, or on your Amazon S3 account.
- the target image will be stored on blitline's S3 account, or on your own S3 account.

Comment: so is it bitline or blitline?

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like

- [**Magick Studio**](http://www.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio/scripts/MagickStudio.cgi)

provided by the developers of ImageMagick themselves? (This is free of charge.)

Or a paid 'software as a service':

- [**Cloudinary**](http://cloudinary.com/faq)
- [**Blitline**](http://www.blitline.com/docs/about)

AFAIU, ...

- Cloudinary offers a RESTful as well as a JSON interface, Blitline only a JSON one.
- Cloudinary probably offers a few more image manipulation features than Blitline.
- Cropping and resizing works with both.
- Blitline is probably cheaper than Cloudinary.

---

Update: sorry, I had forgotten you had mentioned Cloudinary already...

Comment: Something similar, but I'm looking for an API and is a business that's not going to stop providing the service all of a sudden.

Comment: @Harry: Until you provide proof to the contrary for me, in my book *'ImageMagick Studio LLC'* ***IS*** a business... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, [imgix](http://www.imgix.com/) could also be worthwile to investigate. Not a plain ImageMagick wrapper, as they mention themselves, but a rather broad offering in image manipulation commands.

[Their documentation page](http://www.imgix.com/docs) lists examples of commands supplied via the URL, and the [full API](http://www.imgix.com/docs/urlapi)  is documented extensively.